# listbox unselects itself when changing listbox background color

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a listbox and code to make sure it (and other elements) are selected.  I added an ELSE to the code so that if the ListBox has a selected item, it changes the background color to white.  This needs to happen if the previous attempted entry was a duplicate (which changed BG to red), but it was easier to just make that the default.

My comboBox and textBox do not do this.  Any idea what I could do differently so that only the Initialize function clears it?

Thanks,

Here is the code snippet where it clears the listBox selected items.  Comment above line that seems to be causing this.

EDIT: It deselects whenever I change the background color.  It also deselects when I cause a duplicate, which doesn't change the background color.  So the list box is deselecting on its own in many cases. If I can find the cause of one of them (two of which are listed here), then perhaps I can resolve the third one.

```
Function HighlightEmpty(ByVal nameSelect As Boolean, ByVal comboSelect As Boolean, ByVal listSelect As Boolean) As Boolean
' Highlight empty fields
If Not nameSelect Then
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.SignalNameTxtBox.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.SignalNameTxtBox.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

If Not comboSelect Then
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.ComboBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.ComboBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

If Not listSelect Then
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.ListBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else 
    **'This is where it breaks**
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.ListBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)    
End If

' Set focus to first empty field on form
If Not nameSelect Then
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.SignalNameTxtBox.SetFocus
ElseIf Not comboSelect Then
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.ComboBox1.SetFocus
ElseIf Not listSelect Then
    Enter_New_DTC_Form.ListBox1.SetFocus
End If

' Return boolean to trigger message
HighlightEmpty = Not nameSelect Or Not comboSelect Or Not listSelect
End Function
```

Comment: How do you run this function? On what event?

Comment: On Click_Save button (on the form). Every time SAVE is hit, before populating the row and checking if it's a duplicate (which sends a message and deletes the row), it will check to make sure the mandatory fields are selected.  If not, it calls this function to highlight the empty field(s), and then puts focus on the first one. It will then exit the Save sub so they can try again.

Comment: Why don't you use a Sub instead. Above code is more suitable in it. You can all pass values in it. Although Function is not 100% not applicable in executing object methods and properties (basically used to return value), Subs do it better.

Comment: Ok, solved my own problem. So I used the above function, but added a couple of for loops; one to capture what was selected into an array at the beginning, and one to repopulate the list from the array at the end. It looks like spaghetti, but I couldn't find anything on google related to listBox items being unselected when changing background colors. I could post the code, but it's really as simple as it sounds. FWIW, had to reDIM to get array to base size on list; did this for flexibility. This (practice) code will be ported and touched up for actual use. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: In response to L42, I used a function to return a boolean value. It seems more complicated with subs for some reason. I call the function as an argument in an IF statement. Seemed like the most elegant way to do it, and would be my goto method for C or Python. Not that I would use goto...

Answer (score 2):

I realize the original post is over 2 years old but it's still relevant as I experienced this EXACT issue using Excel 2013 and VBA 7.1. I'm just an amateur when it comes to coding, but I came up with the following code as a workaround.

This code would be used after the data has been validated and you're ready to move to the next step.

You end up finding the index of the selected list item, adding 1 to it, setting the selected list item to the *next/previous* item, then setting it back to the actual item. I don't know *why* this is necessary, but it works.

```
'Determine the currently selected list item and set j to the index of it
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then j = i
Next i

'Set j to 1 more than the index of the selected list item
j = j + 1


'If the selected list item isn't the last one, select the next item,
'then re-select the original item
If j < ListBox1.ListCount Then
    ListBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'Set the background color to white
    ListBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)       'and the foreground color to black
    ListBox1.ListIndex = (j)                'Select the NEXT item in the list
    ListBox1.ListIndex = (j - 1)            'Re-select the ORIGINAL item

'If the selected list item is the last one, select the previous item,
'then re-select the original item
ElseIf j = ListBox1.ListCount Then
    ListBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'Set the background color to white
    ListBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)       'Set the foreground color to black
    ListBox1.ListIndex = (j - 2)            'Select the PREVIOUS item in the list
    ListBox1.ListIndex = (j - 1)            'Re-select the ORIGINAL item
End If
```

Hope this helps. I spent a lot of time researching and could not find a solution to the root cause but implemented this code in my own spreadsheet.

Comment: Good call Sometowngeek. I made your suggested change. Thanks.

Comment: It may not be required in this case. I suggested this change because it is a good practice to follow the `If... ElseIf... Else...` in a single block if it relies on a single variable or property, and the action depends on what it has. For example, if the color is red, stop; else if the color is yellow, do a somersault; otherwise, go buy a bag of grapes.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to store the selections, change BackColor then reapply selections;

```
Public Sub UpdateBackgroundColor()
    Dim sel() As Boolean: sel = GetSelectedIndexs()

    list_box.BackColor = &H80000005

    SetSelectedIndexs sel
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedIndexs() As Boolean()
    If list_box.ListCount > 0 Then
        ReDim sel(0 To list_box.ListCount - 1) As Boolean

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To list_box.ListCount - 1
            sel(i) = list_box.Selected(i)
        Next

        GetSelectedIndexs = sel
    Else
        ReDim GetSelectedIndexs(0)
    End If
End Function

Private Function SetSelectedIndexs(sel() As Boolean)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(sel) To UBound(sel)
        list_box.Selected(i) = sel(i)
    Next
End Function
```